# How to replace data inside the localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, local-storage

```js
const newFirst = document.getElementById("changeFName");
const newLast = document.getElementById("changeLName");
const newMail = document.getElementById("changeMail");
const newPass = document.getElementById("changePass");

const saveMe = document.getElementById("btn-save");

newData = (e) => { //mouseclick
    e.preventDefault();
    const first_name = changeFName.value;
    const last_name = changeLName.value;
    const e_mail = changeMail.value;
    const pass_word = changePass.value;

    let user_data = {
        newFirst: first_name,
        newLast: last_name,
        newMail: e_mail,
        newPass: pass_word,
    }

    let clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

    clientsArr.push(user_data);

    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
}

saveMe.addEventListener("click", newData);
```

I've been trying to replace stored data of user using my "signup form" inside the local storage but:

1. the data is not being replace it's just creating new user (name,lastname,email,password)

I recycled my signup code hoping that this will work,

I have also login form that allowing each user to store to do list without changing the to do list of each other.

this is a TO-DO-LIST project from online course.

Comment: If you want to replace an existing user you would need to know which entry in the `clientsArr` it corresponded to, then you can just use `clientsArr[user_index] = user_data;`

Comment: your code snippet here is pushing the new `user_data` into the already existing `users` in your localStorage

Comment: Simple way to do this is to just retrieve the localStorge using getItem  and then add the value. Then remove the key using localStorage.remove('key'), after that use setItem with the same key name which in your case is 'users'

Answer (score 0):

You try use below code

Reference: [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
        localStorage.clickcount = 2;
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a unique field to recognize user like id, email.
using this code you can update your existing user data (without email)

```
const newEmail = document.getElementById("email");
const newName = document.getElementById("name");
const frm = document.getElementById("frm");

frm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = newEmail.value;
  const name = newName.value;
  const userData = { email, name };
  const storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));

  if (!storage) {
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify([userData]));
  } else {
    const userIndex = storage.findIndex(el => el.email === email);
    if (userIndex>=0) {
      storage[userIndex] = userData;
      localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(storage));
    } else {
      storage.push(userData);
      localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(storage));
    }
  }
});

  <form id="frm">
    email: <input id="email" type="text" />
   name: <input id="name" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">save me</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as the power is back, due to typhoon here in the philippines, anyway thanks for answering! Again what i’m trying to do is make the settings page working, and the main function of settings page is to update your stored firstname, lastname, email and password. That you save using the sign up page, i will try your code!once the power is back 